# Hibernate saveOrUpdate creates two instances of an object

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

When creating a new ebject with saveOrUpdate hibernate stores the object in the database and returns it correctly. But an additional object with with some empty columns is created within the same call of the method.

The objects in the database look like this:

```
id  cause   effect  isInTopTen  propability responsibility  scope   title
312 test    test    0           0           NULL            0       NULL
313 test    test    0           2           CUSTOMER        3       test
```

This is the dataclass:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name=HibernateConstants.RISK_TABLE)
public class Risk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    private boolean isInTopTen;
    private String title;
    private String cause;
    private String effect;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Responsibility responsibility;
    private int propability;
    private int scope;
    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.MERGE}) 
    private List<Keyword> keywords;
    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.MERGE}) 
    private List<Action> actions;
    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.MERGE}) 
    private List<ProjectRisk> derivedProjectsRisks;
}
```

This is the way i store objects to the database:
    public class DataUtils {
        private Session session;
        private static DataUtils dataUtils;

```
    private DataUtils() {}

    private void setSession() {
        session = HibernateSessionFactory.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
    }

    public static DataUtils getInstance() {
        if (dataUtils == null) {
            dataUtils = new DataUtils();
        }
        return dataUtils;
    }

    public void storeOne(Object o) {
        setSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(o);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And my hibernate configuration:

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {
    // Singleton
    private HibernateSessionFactory() {}

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getInstance() {
        if (sessionFactory==null) {
            final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    <!-- DB-Connection -->
      <property name="connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/riskManagement</property>
      <property name="connection.username">riskManagement</property>
      <property name="connection.password">riskManagement</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
      <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
      <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>      

      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

      <!-- Classes added to persistence -->
      <mapping class="com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Customer" />
      <mapping class="com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword" />
      <mapping class="com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Project" />
      <mapping class="com.encoway.riskManagement.data.ProjectRisk" />
      <mapping class="com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk" />
      <mapping class="com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Action" />
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Log informations regarding this transaction:

```
Opening new JDBC connection
Created connection to: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/riskManagement, Isolation Level: 2
select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences with (updlock, rowlock) where sequence_name = 'KEYWORD'
update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'KEYWORD'
Generated identifier: 4882432, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator
committing
Processing flush-time cascades
Dirty checking collections
Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
Listing entities:
com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword{id=4882432, name=abc}
insert into KEYWORD (name, id) values (?, ?)
committed JDBC Connection
HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
Releasing JDBC connection
Released JDBC connection
begin
Obtaining JDBC connection
Obtained JDBC connection
initial autocommit status: false
select sequence_next_hi_value from hibernate_sequences with (updlock, rowlock) where sequence_name = 'RISK'
update hibernate_sequences set sequence_next_hi_value = ? where sequence_next_hi_value = ? and sequence_name = 'RISK'
Generated identifier: 4718592, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator
Loading entity: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword#4882432]
select keyword0_.id as id3_0_, keyword0_.name as name3_0_ from KEYWORD keyword0_ where keyword0_.id=?
Result set row: 0
Result row: EntityKey[com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword#4882432]
Resolving associations for [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword#4882432]
Done materializing entity [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword#4882432]
Done entity load
committing
Processing flush-time cascades
Dirty checking collections
Collection found: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.actions#4718592], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
Collection found: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.derivedProjectsRisks#4718592], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
Collection found: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.keywords#4718592], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
Flushed: 3 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 3 collections
Listing entities:
com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk{id=4718592, title=null, scope=0, keywords=[com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword#4882432], cause=abc, effect=abc, derivedProjectsRisks=[], isInTopTen=false, propability=0, actions=[], responsibility=null}
com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword{id=4882432, name=abc}
insert into RISK (cause, effect, isInTopTen, propability, responsibility, scope, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Inserting collection: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.actions#4718592]
Collection was empty
Inserting collection: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.derivedProjectsRisks#4718592]
Collection was empty
Inserting collection: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.keywords#4718592]
insert into RISK_KEYWORD (RISK_id, keywords_id) values (?, ?)
Done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
committed JDBC Connection
HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
Releasing JDBC connection
Released JDBC connection
begin
Obtaining JDBC connection
Obtained JDBC connection
initial autocommit status: false
Generated identifier: 4718593, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator
committing
Processing flush-time cascades
Dirty checking collections
Collection found: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.actions#4718593], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
Collection found: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.derivedProjectsRisks#4718593], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
Collection found: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.keywords#4718593], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
Flushed: 1 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
Flushed: 3 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 3 collections
Listing entities:
com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk{id=4718593, title=abc, scope=3, keywords=[com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword#4882432], cause=abc, effect=abc, derivedProjectsRisks=[], isInTopTen=false, propability=2, actions=[], responsibility=CUSTOMER}
com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Keyword{id=4882432, name=abc}
insert into RISK (cause, effect, isInTopTen, propability, responsibility, scope, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
update KEYWORD set name=? where id=?
Inserting collection: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.actions#4718593]
Collection was empty
Inserting collection: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.derivedProjectsRisks#4718593]
Collection was empty
Inserting collection: [com.encoway.riskManagement.data.Risk.keywords#4718593]
insert into RISK_KEYWORD (RISK_id, keywords_id) values (?, ?)
Done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
committed JDBC Connection
HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
Releasing JDBC connection
Released JDBC connection
```

Comment: Are you sure you really only call `storeOne` once? Can you add some logging code?

Comment: I added the logfile and will try it with merge now. I debugged the code and watched the database. the two objects were created in one call of saveOrUpdate.

Comment: As an aside, neither your `HibernateSessionFactory` nor `DataUtils` class implement the factory pattern correctly. They are ***very much thread unsafe***.

Comment: the approach with session.merge() did not change the problem

Comment: I solved the problem. There is another class calling session.merge() before saving and which is causing the additional object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment: "I solved the problem. There is another class calling session.merge() before saving and which is causing the additional object." So it was simply an individual bug.